# Mi app no inicia al ser desplegada con Vercel

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, vercel

Al desplegar mi app en Vercel desde un repositorio privado en GibHub y luego de configurar las variables de entorno, me sale el típico 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND. No está de más decir que la app funciona perfectamente en local.
La webSite está construida con Node.js y Express usando import y export.

La distribución de las carpetas está así.

```
/desktop/miapp #carpeta que contiene el proyecto

    src -> carpeta que contiene el index.js
        public
        views
        routes
        ...
        index.js
    package.json
    vercel.json
```

El package.json contiene lo siguiente:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-my-app",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "description": "My App",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "prompt": "^1.3.0",
    "qrcodejs": "^1.0.0",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.34"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

y el archivo vercel.json contiene lo siguiente:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/.*",
      "dest": "src/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

He intentado modificar el archivo vercel.json de mil maneras diferentes y luego haciendo el push, pero nada me funciona. He probado cualquier cantidad de configuraciones que veo en los foros, pero no doy con la configuracion correcta. Agradecería mucho su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de pasar toda la tarde probando configuraciones por fin di con la que me funcionó. El problema estaba en el archivo vercel.json. El archivo index.js que inicia mi app está ubicado dentro de la carpeta "src", por lo que el archivo vercel debe estar configurado asi:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./src/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/src/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia exactamente igual mi vercel.json pero ahora dejo de funcionar, en el runtime he intentado varias verciones de node pero no se que ocurre.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "functions": {
    "./index.js": {
      "runtime": "nodejs14.x"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

ahora en vercel me da este error:

```
[12:16:33.566] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[12:16:34.024] Cloning github.com/edwinmoreno77/fatima-app-backend (Branch: main, Commit: c1e5924)
[12:16:34.464] Cloning completed: 440.177ms
[12:16:35.781] Restored build cache
[12:16:35.862] Running "vercel build"
[12:16:36.335] Vercel CLI 32.5.6
**[12:16:36.482] Error: Function Runtimes must have a valid version, for example `now-php@1.0.0`.
[12:16:36.731]**
```